# No provider for RouterOutletMap! in angular2 app

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a routing for my angular2 app. I have seen many questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675921/angular2-rc1-no-provider-for-routeroutletmap) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187235/getting-angular2-error-no-provider-for-router-routeroutlet-router) but none of them helped me.

Here is my `app.route.ts`:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {FormComponent} from './form.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './about-this.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path:'home' , component: FormComponent  },
    { path:'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path:'**'   , component: FormComponent  }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
]
```

and then here is my root component:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavbarComponent} from './shared/navbar.component';
import {appRouterProviders} from './app.routes'


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives:[NavbarComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [appRouterProviders]
})

export class AppComponent {
     title = "Here is Root!";
  }
```

and in the temple is(`app.component.html`):

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

As you can see, I have used `./app.routes` as my route provider.
As a result, I expect, when i use the `http://localhost:4200/home` it brings the form component, but it does not happen. Also, there is no error in console.
What is going wrong?

Update:
I also, bootstraped my app with `main.ts` :

```
import { bootstrap }  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[appRouterProviders] );
```

Comment: when your page loads, refresh it and see if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The router needs to be provided in `bootstrap`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [appRouterProviders])
```

Comment: Did you provide it **only** in `bootstrap` or **also** in `bootstrap`? It should be **only**.

Comment: You definitely have to only provide it in `bootstrap()`. If this doesn't work it's not related to where you provide `appRouterProviders`.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Have you checked you have the latest Angular2 (RC.4) and router (V3-beta.2) version?

Comment: Based on Readme file generated in my project it is **version 1.0.0-beta.10.**

Comment: That's a rather old version and none of your router code will work with this versions because there were substantial changes since then.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: I don't know about TS project configuration or how to update local stuff because I only use Dart and TS only from prepared Plunker templates. You should definitely update to the newest version. Perhaps install newest angular-cli and create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the comments in the above answers I have a few solutions you could try...

First: In the package.json file change

```
"@angular/router": "whatever version you have"
```

to this

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2"
```

Also if you Package.json file doesn't look something like the quickstart [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) then I would suggest coping it over to your project, make the change I noted above, and run an npm install on your project. Then attempt to start your app and see what you get.